# What's wrong with this LiPo battery?

Tags: battery-charging, lipo

I have an 11.1v **LiPo** battery that has be working just fine and it recently dropped to 8.3 volts as it normally does during use. However this time when I plugged it into the charger the charger started to *blink* meaning either the battery is too low to charger or there is a problem with the battery. When I checked the battery's individual cells I made note of their individual charges

- Cell1: 4.15v
- Cell2: 4.15v
- Cell3: 0.0v

How is this even possible? Is my battery toast? It's new and was working fine until this happened.

***NOTES***

- This battery has a balance charging connection w 1 blk & 3 red wires to the connector
- I only have only ever used balanced charging for this battery
- This battery has 16 gauge red/back wires connected to a deans connector for use
- I use this battery with a quad copter uav.
- This battery was freshly charged and only lasted ~1 minute the last time it was used
- I was changing pitch/roll/yaw settings on last use and at one point an ESC started causing a motor to be jittery (happens a lot). As I was throttling down/up (4/5 times) to get the motor to spin correctly the low voltage signal kicked in.
- I was using this batter with my quad copter last night when I got the "low voltage" cut off from my ESCs. Instead of charging this battery I charged another battery and left this one sitting on my counter (room temperature) over night.

## Edit

I just ran a multimeter on each of the wires coming out of the balanced charge connection and here's what I found:

- Wire1(c1): 4.16v
- Wire2(c1+c2): 8.33v (4.16v from cell1 + 4.17v from cell2)
- Wire3(c1+c2+c3): 8.43v (4.16v from cell1 + 4.17v from cell2 + 0.1v from cell3)

## Edit

Using a suggestion in the comments I was able to get a voltage readout of 41.2mV for cell 3. This extremely low as it close to 3.7V.

Comment: This is unfortunate, but **** happens.

Comment: yeah, **** happens but such a fail without any external cause seems odd to me. I'm betting on a broken contact somewhere... If you measure the 8ish V across the "big" wires nothing is broken though.

Comment: I was going to try to charge cell3 (0.1v) as a 1 cell lipo but the charger will just tell me the cell is too low to charge. I would try to charge cell3 as NIMH to get it up to 3v but I don't have a NIMH charger and I don't know enough about batteries to be comfortable with a hack like that anyway.

Comment: 4.15 V is pretty high for a cells that you "ran down".  Either you didn't get much flight time or you recharged them and didn't tell us.

Comment: @gbarry the last time I flew this copter I was changing pitch/roll/yaw settings and at one point one of the brushless motors was acting jittery. I see that often with these ESCs so I throttled down and back a few times as that usually fixes the issue. The low-voltage signal kicked in which was odd because this battery had been freshly charged. This is when I left the battery on the counter and went to bed. Note- the motor didn't start coopering before the batter died, perhaps that could be part of the cause?

Comment: When you charge, do you balance charge or just a simple quick charge? BTW: A simpler way to check cell voltages is to measure pairs instead of pin-to-ground: gnd->c1, c1->c2, c2->c3. That's how they're wired internally, each "pair" soldered to each cell's + and - terminals.

Comment: When you were measuring 0 volts, it was possible that you had a loose wire, or if there is a protection circuit it may have kicked in.  Now that you measure 0.1 volts, it suggests that the connections are there and the battery is just dead.  Probably an internal failure of some sort.

Comment: So is the only option now just to toss this battery? There's no way to recover it?